# Retrieve data from table which uses mongoose populate() function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, ecmascript-6

I have a model `'user'` of two properties `'username'` & `'plan'` where `'plan'` is a reference of another model `'plan'` where properties are `'name'` & `'description'`. now when I use following Query in API to retrieve data-

```
`user.find().populate('plan')`
```

I am trying to render this data in front-end using

```
this.state.users.map(re => (
    <tr key={re._id}>
        <th>{re.username}</th>
        <th>{re.plan}</th>
    </tr>
)
```

Here `re.plan` returns the `_id` of the property. To get the `name` property, I have to use `re.plan.name` . Which returns an error as I have some properties which does not have any `plan` property.
Sample data from the Query ---

```
{
    "_id": "5a8be9ce4f506927a8d2cacb",
    "username": "kjbfhisdugfiasdb",   
    "plan": {
        "_id": "5a64bbd3f671402b90ce5fc9",
        "name": " test 3"
    },
},
{
    "_id": "5a82bcb4c72440221442399f",
    "username": "test",
}
```

How to resolve this issue?
Thanks in advance

Comment: One hacking method to bypass this is `(re.plan || {}).name`. It takes an empty object `{}` when the left-side of `||` is null or undefined

Comment: all plan fields become " ", empty.
I have accepted Prasanna's answer. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just render like `{re.plan && re.plan.name }`

Comment: Thanks man. Works perfectly. Just to get clarification why it's working?

Comment: This is what is called a conditional rendering in react. You are simply rendering `re.plan.name` , if there is a `re.plan`. If `re.plan` is undefined, we get a statement, `undefined & re.plan.name` in which case the statement after the and is not evaluated as a single undefined makes it unrenderable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional rendering like this:

```
<th>{re.plan ? re.plan.name : ""}</th>
```

Comment: all plan fields become " ", empty